# Perl - check for presence of IP address in a file

Tags: perl

I understand that this question can be classified as is a frequently asked question, but I do not find any answers for my specific scenario. I have been trying to get this done for the past few hours.

Simple scenario:

I have an IP address in a variable, I want to check if the IP address is present in a file (which has list of IP addresses).

Below is the part of my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $list = "IP addresses: ";
my $ipv4 = $domObj->getElementsByTagName('ipv4-address');
open my $fh, '<' , 'sample.txt';
while(<$fh>)
{
    if(/\b$ipv4\b/)
    {
        $list .= $ipv4;
        print "IP address found!!";
    }
}
```

When I run the above code it shows me some unintialized variable error. It does not find the IP address value present in `$ipv4` correction from the `sample.txt` file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Always put `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the top of your perl code as that'll highlight mistakes you've made in your code.

Comment: The above is just a part of my code. I always add use strict and warnings to my script document.

Comment: then why not include them in your [mcve] in your question? currently the code you've supplied wouldn't run if you did add them

Comment: Added. Can you tell me what went wrong?

Comment: The only possible way to get the warning in what you show is if the call to `$domObj` fails to return for `$ipv4`, so then it is used (evaluated) while undefined ("uninitialized") in the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning in the (edited) question can only be due to  `$domObj`, see end. We cannot fix that here.

But there is also a direct error in the shown code so let's clear that up.

Your IPv4 address contains `.` which is special when used in a regex.  So when you use `$ipv4` as a pattern in a regex those `.` match any character and the whole thing is wrong.  (It should still match the literal `.` as well but it allows other characters, too.)

Form the regex pattern using [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html), which escapes all non-word characters

```
my $re_ipv4 = quotemeta $ivp4;

my @list;

while (<$fh>) 
{
    while (/\b($re_ipv4)\b/g) {
        push @list, $1;
    }
}
```

I put them on an array, which you can later `join` in a string.  If you wish to form a string directly remember to add a space, `$list .= "$1 "`

Inside of a regex this is effected by `\Q` (and `\E` to stop it)

```
/\b\Q($ipv4)\E\b/
```

Search for [`\Q` in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators). It is also documented in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) and [perlbackslash](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html).

---

The edited question has one clear way to get the mentioned warning. It seems that

```
$domObj->getElementsByTagName('ipv4-address');
```

doesn't do as expected and returns `undef` (or nothing) and thus `$ipv4` stays undefined.

Then it is used (evaluated) in a regex and you get the appropriate warning.

Another possibility is that the warning is in fact emited from `getElementsByTagName` but you should be able to tell since the warning should show the line of code at which it's triggered.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Will test it and accept the answer!! I did not have idea about the "dot" being special in regex and it had to be escaped. Thanks again! Is there any other way to escape special characters like dot or * ??

Comment: @BalaKrishnan  Inside a regex itself you can use `/\Q...\E/`, which does the same.  Thanks for the reminder, adding to the answer ..

Comment: But the dots would match literal dots in the input, too. So the IP addresses should match. This should only lead to false positives, shouldn't it?

Comment: Thanks a bunch! @zdim Will test this tomorrow morning.

Comment: @simbabque  Right -- I don't see from the question why it fails to match and throws error so I just called the error.  I should comment (adding), thank you.

Comment: Essentially `say '1.2.3' =~ m/1.2.3/;` prints `1`, but so does `say '112233' =~ m/1.2.3/;`

Comment: @simbabque  Right, and one can come up with somewhat realistic concerns like `10220.30.40` "matching" `10.20.30.40`.  Or `1_2_3` for `1.2.3` which I could _imagine_ actually showing up in data (this is what I tested with)

Comment: Yes, definitely. I'm not saying you're wrong This is a good point. I'm just wondering if you are solving their problem. I think something else is going on in OP's code.

Comment: @simbabque  The same thinking here, and their update clears it up, updating the answer

Comment: @BalaKrishnan  Edited the answer to reflect edits in your question.